# ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

Python gives an error at the variable T. The others above do work, I do not see any differences?  Anyone can identify the problem. The error is:

ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 10000

```
N = 10000
Cpl = np.random.normal(0.6, 0.1, N)    
Cs = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, N)
P = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, N)
Sd = np.random.normal(4, 0.1, N)
N = np.random.normal(3600, 100, N)
alpha = np.random.normal(8, 0.01, N)
Hs = np.random.normal(5, 1, N)
rho_w = np.random.normal(1025, 5, N)
rho_s = np.random.normal(2600, 50, N)
dn50 = np.random.normal(3.5, 0.1, N)
T = np.random.normal(9, 1, N)

mc = bw.MonteCarlo(Pf=2e-5,
               zfunc = 'vdmeer',
               Cpl=Cpl, 
               Cs= Cs, 
               P=P, 
               Sd=Sd, 
               N=N, 
               T=T, 
               alpha=alpha, 
               Hs=Hs, 
               rho_w=rho_w, 
               rho_s=rho_s, 
               dn50=dn50)
```

Comment: Which `N` are you trying to use?  `N=1000` or `N = np.random.normal(3600, 100, N)`

Comment: ah I see. I named two variables equally... Problem solved